# Not able to add contact using contacts_service in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Actually I am building a card reader application in which data is coming from the ML model and get stored in the mycontrollers function. But on using ContactsService.addContact(contact); I am getting error. Although contact is saved in the app but not in the phone's contact list.

code:

```
 void saveContactInPhone() {
try {

  print("saving Conatct");
  Contact contact = Contact();
    print("fi");
    contact.displayName = myController1.text ; 
    contact.phones = [Item(label: "mobile", value: myController4.text)];
    // contact.emails = [Item(label: "email", value: myController3.text)];
    contact.company = myController2.text;
    print("fi2");

  ContactsService.addContact(contact);
  print("object");      

} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

Error:

```
I/flutter ( 1615): form init
```

I/flutter ( 1615): /data/user/0/com.example.camera_app/app_flutter/2020-05-29 23:35:12.398628.png
I/flutter ( 1615): Going Image
I/flutter ( 1615): 404
I/flutter ( 1615): Image Send
I/flutter ( 1615): form come listenForSinglecontact
I/flutter ( 1615): saving
I/flutter ( 1615): fi
I/flutter ( 1615): fi2
I/flutter ( 1615): object
E/flutter ( 1615): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid envelope
E/flutter ( 1615): #0 StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:571:7)
E/flutter ( 1615): #1 MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter ( 1615):
E/flutter ( 1615): #2 MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:329:12)
E/flutter ( 1615): #3 ContactsService.addContact (package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart:83:16)
E/flutter ( 1615): #4 _FormState.saveData (package:camera_app/screens/form.dart:249:23)
E/flutter ( 1615): #5 _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
E/flutter ( 1615): #6 _InkResponseState.build. (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
E/flutter ( 1615): #7 GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter ( 1615): #8 TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
E/flutter ( 1615): #9 BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
E/flutter ( 1615): #10 BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:217:7)
E/flutter ( 1615): #11 PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9)
E/flutter ( 1615): #12 PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter ( 1615): #13 PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes. (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)
E/flutter ( 1615): #14 _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:379:8)
E/flutter ( 1615): #15 PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:120:18)
E/flutter ( 1615): #16 PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:106:7)
E/flutter ( 1615): #17 GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:218:19)
E/flutter ( 1615): #18 GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:198:22)
E/flutter ( 1615): #19 GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter ( 1615): #20 GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter ( 1615): #21 GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I was missing the permissions part. Ohh I am such a newbie in Flutter.

This worked for me finally for saving a contact in MAin Contacts or phone directory.

So let's use contacts_service 0.4.6 for it.
First, add dependency as :

```
dependencies:  
contacts_service: ^0.4.6
```

Permissions:

For Android 
Add the following permissions to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

For iOS 
Set the NSContactsUsageDescription in your Info.plist file

```
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>  
<string>This app requires contacts access to function properly.</string>
```

Import library:

```
import 'package:contacts_service/contacts_service.dart';
```

Basically,

```
 final myController1 = TextEditingController();
 final myController2 = TextEditingController();
 ...
```

These are variables used to store the value entered by the user in Textfield or Textform. The value can be query by using `myController1.text`
We can also store Contact class objects as:

> ```
>    newContact.givenName = "Some name";
>             newContact.emails = [
>               Item(label: "email", value: "abc@gmail.com")
>             ];
>             newContact.company = myController2.text;
>             newContact.phones = [
>               Item(label: "mobile", value: "123456789")
>             ];
> ```

Code for just saving contact:

```
     Future<void> saveContactInPhone() async {
    try {

      print("saving Conatct");
      PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

    if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
      await Permission.contacts.request();
      PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

      if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
        Contact newContact = new Contact();
        newContact.givenName = myController1.text;
        newContact.emails = [
          Item(label: "email", value: myController3.text)
        ];
        newContact.company = myController2.text;
        newContact.phones = [
          Item(label: "mobile", value: myController4.text)
        ];
        newContact.postalAddresses = [
          PostalAddress(region: myController6.text)
        ];
        await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);

      } else {
        //_handleInvalidPermissions(context);
      }
    } else {
      Contact newContact = new Contact();
        newContact.givenName = myController1.text;
        newContact.emails = [
          Item(label: "email", value: myController3.text)
        ];
        newContact.company = myController2.text;
        newContact.phones = [
          Item(label: "mobile", value: myController4.text)
        ];
        newContact.postalAddresses = [
          PostalAddress(region: myController6.text)
        ];
        await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
    }
      print("object");      

    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Similarily I found too much difficulty in reflecting the changes on the actual phone directory. So I came up with this solution:

```
Future<void> saveContactInPhone() async {
    try {
      print("saving Conatct");
      PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

      if (permission != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        await Permission.contacts.request();
        PermissionStatus permission = await Permission.contacts.status;

        if (permission == PermissionStatus.granted) {
          if (widget.checkPrev == 'for_edit') {
            // Contact updatedContact = new Contact();
            Iterable<Contact> updatedContact =
                await ContactsService.getContacts(query: myController1.text);

            Contact updatedContact1 = new Contact();
            updatedContact1 = updatedContact.first;
            await ContactsService.deleteContact(updatedContact1);
            Contact newContact = new Contact();
            newContact.givenName = myController1.text;
            newContact.emails = [
              Item(label: "email", value: myController3.text)
            ];
            newContact.company = myController2.text;
            newContact.phones = [
              Item(label: "mobile", value: myController4.text)
            ];
            newContact.postalAddresses = [
              PostalAddress(region: myController6.text)
            ];
            await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
          } else if (widget.checkPrev == 'from_btn') {
            Contact newContact = new Contact();
            newContact.givenName = myController1.text;
            newContact.emails = [
              Item(label: "email", value: myController3.text)
            ];
            newContact.company = myController2.text;
            newContact.phones = [
              Item(label: "mobile", value: myController4.text)
            ];
            newContact.postalAddresses = [
              PostalAddress(region: myController6.text)
            ];
            await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (widget.checkPrev == 'for_edit') {
          // Contact updatedContact = new Contact();
          Iterable<Contact> updatedContact =
              await ContactsService.getContacts(query: myController1.text);

          await ContactsService.deleteContact(updatedContact.first);
          // Contact updatedContact1 = new Contact();
          // updatedContact1= updatedContact.first;
          Contact newContact = new Contact();
          newContact.givenName = myController1.text;
          newContact.emails = [Item(label: "email", value: myController3.text)];
          newContact.company = myController2.text;
          newContact.phones = [
            Item(label: "mobile", value: myController4.text)
          ];
          newContact.postalAddresses = [
            PostalAddress(region: myController6.text)
          ];
          await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
        } else if (widget.checkPrev == 'from_btn') {
          Contact newContact = new Contact();
          newContact.givenName = myController1.text;
          newContact.emails = [Item(label: "email", value: myController3.text)];
          newContact.company = myController2.text;
          newContact.phones = [
            Item(label: "mobile", value: myController4.text)
          ];
          newContact.postalAddresses = [
            PostalAddress(region: myController6.text)
          ];
          await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

This will save a contact as well as edit the contact whenever make changes in the current app.